# accuracy for lstm network

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I wrote a code for lstm network. my data was string and I used word2vec model to convert them into int. My target is the class labe(it is int for example: fault1, fault2,...). But when I run my code accuraccy is always 1 or 0. What is wrong? Is it for that accuracy is not for int target? loss function is incorrect?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import gensim
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, LSTM, Flatten
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
alarm=pd.read_excel('alarmdata.xlsx')
alarm_test=pd.read_excel('testdata.xlsx')
x=alarm['Alarm_tag']
y=alarm['Fault']
x_test=alarm_test['Alarm_tag']
y_test=alarm_test['Fault']
v=x.unique().tolist()
n=x.nunique()
v_test=x_test.unique().tolist()
n_test=x_test.nunique()
c=0
l=0
w=0
k=[[] for j in range(1261)]
q=[[] for j in range(1261)]
for i in range(6305):
    if l<6305:
        while w<5:        
           k[c].append(x.loc[l]) 
           w=w+1
           l=l+1
    w=0
    c=c+1 
    i=l+5
c=0
l=0
w=0
z=np.reshape(k, (1261,5))
for i in range(6305):
    if l<6305:
        while w<5:        
           q[c].append(y.loc[l]) 
           w=w+1
           l=l+1
    w=0
    c=c+1 
    i=l+5 
r=np.reshape(q, (1261,5))
#testdata
c=0
l=0
w=0
k_test=[[] for j in range(240)]
q_test=[[] for j in range(240)]
for i in range(1200):
    if l<1200:
        while w<5:        
           k_test[c].append(x_test.loc[l]) 
           w=w+1
           l=l+1
    w=0
    c=c+1 
    i=l+5
c=0
l=0
w=0
z_test=np.reshape(k_test, (240,5))
for i in range(1200):
    if l<1200:
        while w<5:        
           q_test[c].append(y_test.loc[l]) 
           w=w+1
           l=l+1
    w=0
    c=c+1 
    i=l+5 
r_test=np.reshape(q_test, (240,5))
c=0
l=0
w=0
all_alarm=[[] for j in range(6305)]
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(k, size=10, window=1, min_count=1, workers=10, iter=10)
X = model[model.wv.vocab]
for  i in range(46):
     specific_alarm=v[i]
     for j in range(6305):
         if x[j]== specific_alarm:
             all_alarm[j]=X[i]
c=0   
l=0
w=0
g=[[] for j in range(1261)]
for i in range(6305):
    if l<6305:       
        while w<5:        
           g[c].append(all_alarm[l]) 
           w=w+1
           l=l+1
    w=0
    c=c+1 
    i=l+5 
for  i in range(46):
     specific_alarm=v[i]
     for j in range(6305):
         if x[j]== specific_alarm:
             all_alarm[j]=X[i]
c=0   
l=0
w=0
g=[[] for j in range(1261)]
for i in range(6305):
    if l<6305:       
        while w<5:        
           g[c].append(all_alarm[l]) 
           w=w+1
           l=l+1
    w=0
    c=c+1 
    i=l+5 
b = np.asarray(g)
#x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(b,r, test_size=0.3)

#testdata
c=0
l=0
w=0
all_alarmtest=[[] for j in range(1200)]
model2 = gensim.models.Word2Vec(k_test, size=10, window=1, min_count=1, workers=10, iter=10)
X = model[model.wv.vocab]
for  i in range(n_test):
     specific_alarmtest=v_test[i]
     for j in range(1200):
         if x_test[j]== specific_alarmtest:
             all_alarmtest[j]=X[i]
c=0   
l=0
w=0
g_test=[[] for j in range(240)]
for i in range(1200):
    if l<1200:       
        while w<5:        
           g_test[c].append(all_alarmtest[l]) 
           w=w+1
           l=l+1
    w=0
    c=c+1 
    i=l+5 

b_test=np.asarray(g_test)
b = np.asarray(g)
#train model
model= Sequential()
#model.add(Embedding(input_dim=1261, output_dim=1024, input_length=10))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(5,10,)))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(b, r, validation_data=(b_test, r_test), epochs = 100, batch_size =1261)
#model.fit(b, r, epochs = 100, batch_size =100)`
```

Comment: this code is pretty hard to read. Can you add comments to describe what you're doing?

Comment: @Marat Hi. I used alarm data which relate to a speciall fault. As alarm data is string type I uesed word embedding to convert them to int. Then I train the lstm model with this data and I want to predict correct target(fault of the alarm data which is 1,2,6) for the test data.

Comment: This comment is not enough, as it doesn't describe the content of data structures and intent behind code statements. Please, try to add comments throughout the code.

Comment: @Marat Well, throughout the code, first I spilt data into sequences of 5 alarms. Then this data is the input of the word embedding. Word embedding convert this data into vectors of lentgh 10. Every row of this matrix is for an unique word. Therefore I uese this matrix to creat my data. Then I split this new data into sequences of 5 alarm. In fact now my string data is int. After that lstm network is trines.